# Rewriting linear equation

Tags: regression, data-transformation, linear, back-transformation

So I have a linear equation produced in R: logBodyWt = -1.08968 + 1.22496 x logBrainWt

And that's all groovy but there is a question in a module which asks me to

"Rewrite your model as a non-linear equation relating brain weight to body weight".

We have not covered this as far as I can tell. Could someone help explain how to do this and why we would do this?
thank you

Comment: did you transform the data before fitting the model (e.g. by taking logs), or equivalently were the data so transformed before you got them? I find it surprising to imagine that body weight only increases 22.5% faster than brain weight... but if we're looking at say log-scale data that might make much more sense.

Comment: yes, this data has been log transformed. I'll provide you with another example which I got wrong in a online module. This is the fitted equation for a linear model BodyWt = 6634.198 + 26.891*GrowthRate. It had to be transformed, and then I wrote this as a NON-linear equation GrowthRate = 0.037 x BodyWt - 246.707. But my tutor said that is just the transfored linear equation. I am supposed to" Rewrite your model as a non-linear equation relating growth rate to body weight". How do I re-write this? Do i just rearrange something?

Comment: 1. The information that the data are transformed is *critical* to answering the question correctly. Please edit that information into the question. 2. Since this is clearly for a class, please add the `self-study` tag, read its [tag-wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) and modify your question to follow the guidelines on asking such questions. In particular, you'll need to clearly identify what steps you've taken to solve the problem yourself, and indicate the specific help you need at the point you struck difficulty.

Comment: The point of the question appears to be to re-write the log-scale fit back in terms of the original untransformed variables (back-transforming the fit). This will convert the linear relationship between log-brain-weight and log-body-weight to a power relationship between brain weight and body weight. Numerous questions on CV deal with this issue. tags like `[regression]` with either `[data-transformation]` or `[back-transformation]` may be productive, and `log-log` might be productive but may be overly restrictive (Google searches of this site may also help since they also see comments)

Comment: I've edited your equation to at least indicate the actual model you fitted. This will improve the chances your question will be understood.

Comment: Hint: what is the inverse function of the log function? That might not have been covered explicitly in your statistics course, but you probably have encountered that issue in other courses.